# Get File names from assets folder for files only with .txt extension

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Current I have this code:

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
                AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
                try {
                     items.addAll(Arrays.asList(assetManager.list("")));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Which gives me an arraylist of all the file names in the assets folder. 
However I need to  filter this so that the arraylist only has the file names of files that have the .txt extension and then remove the .txt from each items name.

So the current code would result in:

```
test.txt
pi.txt
sounds
hippo.png
square.xml
seven.txt
```

but when I need as the arraylist content would be:

```
test 
pi 
seven
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you would need to do

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
for (String file : assetManager.list("")) {
    if (file.endsWith(".txt"))
        items.add(file);
}
```

If you want to strip the `.txt` extension from the file names you can do

```
...
    items.add(file.replaceAll(".txt$", ""));
...
```